# How difficult is it to determine the owner of some bitcoins?

Tags: privacy, hacking, silk-road

When Bitcoin was making the media waves back in 2011, a lot of it focused on the anonymity aspect of bitcoins, the hacks, and the illegal contents of the silk road onion address. From my limited understanding, it didn't seem like bitcoin wallet owners and transactions were all that anonymous, only merely obfuscated.

I feel like one would have to go out of their way to really make their bitcoin ownership anonymous.

I would like empirical resources on:

1) finding a user through a block chain

2) further obfuscating ownership of bitcoins

and any other currently relevant or useful literature. Perhaps a case study of an actual investigation on a bitcoin holder. (Like tracking down perps in the bigger security breaches)

Comment: I agree with Colin Dean, possible duplicate.

Comment: @gosmond let me get this straight, I had a unique question that got edited into a duplicate question and then closed? wtf. well I'll check out the other answer on that question